# How to get information from two tables

Tags: mysql

I want to extract some information from two different table in one database,
[(first table): id-nbrNight-........]
[(second table): id-........]

I want to extract the nbrNight from the first table & the id from the second table:
so in my case I write this, but I don't know how to rassemble this two line in one line:

```
SELECT sum(nbrNight) as night FROM firsttab
SELECT count(`id`) as id FROM secondtab
```

I wirte this to rassemble this two line:

```
SELECT sum(nbrNight) as night,count(`id`) FROM firsttab,secondtab
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: @help me please to rassemble -- how are they related?  What field ties them together.

Comment: Do you just need the two results on one single line? I haven't gotten if the rows in the two tables have a relation and you need to JOIN the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to combine the result from two query like

```
SELECT sum(nbrNight) as night FROM firsttab
UNION
SELECT count(`id`) as id FROM secondtab
```

(OR) do a `JOIN` with both tables using a common column between them (if any present) like below (assuming `id` is the common column between them)

```
SELECT sum(t1.nbrNight) as nightsum, count(t2.`id`) as idcount
FROM firsttab t1 JOIN secondtab t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: The first query returns two rows. OP specified returning results on a single row. The second query may return a single row, but it's very unlikely that the result will match the OP specification.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the queries as inline views; reference those queries as a rowsource (like a table) in another query.

Since each query returns a single row, you can safely perform a `JOIN` operation, without need for any join predicate (aka `CROSS JOIN`).

For example:

```
SELECT f.night
     , s.id 
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(nbrNight) AS night FROM firsttab ) f
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM secondtab ) s
```

---

Another option (since both queries are guaranteed to return exactly one row, if they don't return an error) is to include the query in the SELECT list of another query. It's not necessary to include a column alias in the subquery, but we can assign an alias.

For example:

```
SELECT ( SELECT SUM(nbrNight) FROM firsttab ) AS night
     , ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM secondtab ) AS id
```

---

If either of the queries were returning more than one column, then the approach in the first example will still work. The inline view queries can return multiple expressions, and we can reference those expressions in the outer query. With the pattern in the second example, that imposes a restriction that the subqueries must return only one expression (one column).

As an example to demonstrate an inline view returning more than one column, the inline view **`f`** returns three expressions:

```
SELECT f.night
     , f.cnt
     , f.min_nbr
     , s.id 
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(nbrNight)   AS night
              , COUNT(nbrNight) AS cnt
              , MIN(nbrNight)   AS min_nbr
          FROM firsttab 
       ) f
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM secondtab ) s
```